# Retreiving data from pandas dataframe and input the values in os.system() command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, os.system

I have a Pandas dataframe in which a whole column of numerical values should be fed as an input to a command from `os.system()`. This os.system()  is executing a a .exe file as this

```
 os.system(r'xxxx.exe --file "Input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start 0 --end 10000')
```

This start to end values in this command should be taking values from the column of my dataframe.
i tried Looping through my column of df.

```
for i in df['xxx']:
 os.system(r'xxxx.exe --file "Input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start i --end i')
```

**Both start and end values can be same**. But Looping through and feeding a variable in this command doesnt work. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in the column?

Comment: 0        4330.468750
1        5021.093750
2        5196.093750
3        5678.515625
4        5818.359375
           ...                         Hi the data in column Looks like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in df['xxx']:
    os.system(r'xxxx.exe --file "Input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start {} --end {}'.format(i, i))
```

Comment: it does not work. The program runs but the Output is not stored in the Output Folder. But only when i give the raw input i mean the number it works. But by this it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
vals = df['col_name'].values.tolist() # Will fetch all the values of that column in a list form
```

Now you can try sending them, as required

I'm writing answer as per my understanding, that you want to send first & last value of the list

```
os.system(r'xxxx.exe --file "Input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start {} --end {}'.format(vals[0], vals[-1]))
```

Comment: Not the first and last values. I mean each value in vals can be used for both start and end. But i tried it .it doesnt work. The result would extract Images according to the number in the Output but it doesnt extract.

Comment: In that case, @RajeshBhat's answer will work. If even after passing the values, you are not getting the expected answer, then you need to look into your `xxxx.exe` application, that is the one which will get you result. Or post its code, someone from SO will help you